# Unable to add iAd to Spritekit Swift programatically

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I just finished making my first game for ios with swift and spritekit and was thinking about implementing iAds banner or interstitial ad in the main menu. But the problem is that I made the title screen programtically without any storyboards. I searched googled around but I was unable to find any tutorial or a easy to understand sample that teaches me how to implement iAd to the GameScene programatically. I would love some tips or examples from you !

I was planning to integrate iAds within MainScene but cannot find a solution to implement the ad.

```
import iAd
class MainScene: SKScene , ADBannerViewDelegate {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create two variables:-

```
var bannerView = ADBannerView()
var isBannerVisible = false
```

Then in your viewDidLoad or didMove to view put:-

```
bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view!.frame.size.height, self.view!.frame.width, 80)
bannerView.delegate = self
isBannerVisible = false
```

Next step is to add the following functions:-

```
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

        if(isBannerVisible == false){

            if(bannerView.superview == nil){

                self.view?.addSubview(bannerView)

            }

            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerShow", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height)
            UIView.commitAnimations()

            isBannerVisible = true

        }

}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

        if(isBannerVisible == true){

            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerHide", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height)
            UIView.commitAnimations()
            isBannerVisible = false

        }

}
```

Along with this make sure you add the ADBannerViewDelegate and import iAd which i see you already have, and this should work. Let me know if you have any issues, this is what i use in my swift spritekit games.

Good Luck,

Rachel

Comment: Thank you Rachel ! I wanted to ask you some question. Is it possible to show the iad in only one GameScene since the ads shows up in all other scenes ? And since I've never uploaded to the appstore, I wanted to know if there  are some other setups for the ads  before uploading  ? For example in android I always set the app Id to the admobs, but for the iAd is  the code you provided enough ?

Comment: Try bannerView.hidden = true. As for what to do for submitting to the app store you must set up your Agreements, Tax and Banking on iTunes connect. No key is needed for your app, but once your app is on the app store you will find that the iAds wont show straight away. This is due to your app being checked by two teams, first team checks that your app is suitable for the app store, and the second team checks if your app can support iAds, which takes longer than the first check. Don't worry though as it only takes a few days after being on the app store for it to work. Hope this helps